# References about the module of extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $A, B$ be two $R$ modules. Let us consider $E(A, B)$ the set of classes of the extension of $A$ by $B$. Are there any known references on the structure of this set as a $R$ module?

Comment: What are you really looking for? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005619/how-do-i-understand-the-module-structure-on-yoneda-ext?rq=1)? The general definition of $\mathsf{Ext}$ as a derived functor (which abstractly but unambiguously gives a module structure)?

Comment: I'd like to know if anyone has studied if the equivalence between E(A, B) end Ext holds also as modules.

Comment: Can you indicate me someone please? Since I have seen this equivalence only as Groups.

Comment: I know this book, but if I'm not wrong the above equivalence it is proved as groups, since it is proved the linearity of the Baer sum. I'm looking for a definition of external product in $E(A,B)$, and a proof that $Ext^1(A,B) \cong E(A,B)$ as $R$-module. Can you eventually indicate some result of the book that could help me?

Comment: And it happened again, answers in comments. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/36082/1650